# CTE approach to avoid cursor update of each rows of table on result of previous row sets

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I want to update each row iteratively, when row is updating it should use previous latest updated values, but by using CTE approach to avoid cursor

Pseudo code of cursor:

```
Cursor{

--when cursor on row 1
update @table
set Balance=dbo.somefunction(sum of balance before row<1 i.e 0)

--when cursor on row 2
update @table
set Balance=dbo.somefunction(sum of balance before row<2 i.e 950)
.
.
.

};

Declare @table table(id int,col int,col2 int,balance int);

INSERT INTO @table
values(1,200,50,0),(2,60,150,0),(3,250,3,0),(4,65,2,0);
```

Final result would look like this:

```
1   200 50  950
2   60  150 1
3   250 3   3
4   65  2   50
```

Comment: Do you realize that your desired result is not consistent with the sample data ?. Where does that 950 come from ?.

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server 2008?  It is not longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

The row_number() function is usually used to identify the previous rows.

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (order by id) as row
  from table
)
select *, 
       (select sum(cte2.balance)
        from cte as cte2
        where cte2.row < cte1.row) as SumBalance
from cte as cte1
order by id
```

Although your id column could already make the same task of identifying the previous rows, so you don't really need the CTE.

```
select *, 
       (select sum(cte2.balance)
        from cte as cte2
        where cte2.id < cte1.id) as SumBalance
from cte as cte1
order by id
```

And finally, you could use a variable to store and increment the sum of balances, so you don't even need a subquery.

```
declare @SumBalance int = 0

select *, @SumBalance = @SumBalance + Balance as SumBalance
from table
order by id
```